# Run sequences of multiple SWRL rules in protege

Tags: ontology, protege, swrl, sqwrl

I have several SWRL rules that use the result of each other.
Currently, I can run the rules one by one through the SWRL/SQWRL  tabs.

Is there a way to run these rules in succession in such a way that I do not have to run them one by one?

Comment: I cannot follow you. From what I understand, in SWRLTab all selected rules will be executed by using the rule engine Drools. Regarding SQWRL Tab, this is a query tab, indeed only a single query will be executed once.

Comment: sorry to take your time.For some reason, I could not check the rules checkbox .creating a new ontology solved the problem.